# Bridge between Framework Flutter and JUCE

Tags: flutter, bridge, juce

The article [flutter-vs-juce](https://stackshare.io/stackups/flutter-vs-juce) describes well the advantages of each framework.
I would like to combine both frameworks in order to take advantage of the individual frameworks. Does anyone have a solution for this or has something similar been done before?

Im speziellen Anwendungsfall würde ich die Audioverarbeitung von JUCE abwickeln lassen, während Flutter das User Interface liefern soll. (Flutter Apps sehen echt brilliant aus.)

Comment: At what level would you like to combine the to? JUCE as backend with Flutter doing all UI or mix and match JUCE drawing with Flutter?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Juce is supposed to handle the audio control and Flutter to provide the UI: Read in the audio files and functions such as start, stop or pause should be controlled by Flutter.

Comment: juce is not really a framework, it is a wrapper library that also mimics UI which makes use of its own draw call mechanism. But nothing stops you from wrapping the wrappers in a framework and write UI adaptors. It also doesnt support metal very well, so you will run in trouble on the macplatform or you are forced to use JUCE for everything limiting your UI to the JUCE way of doing it.